# What happens with return address value when new function is called

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel, return-value, cpu-registers

Imagine this code

```
int main()
{
    f();
}

void f() { g(); }
void g() { cout << "hello" << endl; }
```

When f is called, in RA(return address) register stores the address in main from which f was called (f to know where to jump when finishes). When f calls g, it should set RA to address in f, g to know where to return. So how is this done? Does is store RA for f in a temporary place or something else, not to overwrite old value?

Thanks.

Comment: Which compiler? This is 100% implementation-defined and has very little to do with the C++ language. And I think the answer is "stack frames".

Comment: In stack frames is stored return value, not the address, I think (otherwise RA register would be meaningless)

Comment: Well I'm not sure how else you expect it to work

Comment: Use your compiler to print out the assembly language listing.

Answer (score 0):

Without any optimizations, the usual process in your example:

- main() - push return address on "stack", call f().
- f(): push return address, call g().
- g(): print, then pop return address and move into program counter
  register.
- f(): pop return address, move into program counter
- main(): end program.

This is theory.  Your compiler may emit different code.

**Edit 1:**
For exact specifics, tell your compiler to print the assembly language.

Comment: So what's the meaning of RA register?

Comment: Dunno.  Does not exist on Intel.  Nearest on ARM would be link register, R14.

Comment: What processor are you using?